# Was Guido d'Arezzo the one who invented the diatonic scale?

Tags: history

During Music History class I was taught that Guido d'Arezzo had composed [*the hymn to St. John*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fV18OTmmA3Y) and had made the *ut-re-mi-fa-sol-la-si* (solfege) pattern.

Here are the lyrics to the first verse:

> **Ut** queant laxis
>
> **Re**sonare fibris
>
> **Mi**ra gestorum
>
> **Fa**muli tuorum
>
> **Sol**ve polluti
>
> **La**bii reatum
>
> **S**ancte **I**ohannes

In English, this is:

> **Do** let our voices
>
> **Re**sonate most purely
>
> **Mi**racles telling
>
> **Fa**r greater than many
>
> **So l**et our tongues be
>
> **La**vish in your praises
>
> **S**aint **J**ohn the Baptist

So, does this mean he was also the one who had invented the diatonic scale?

Comment: Guido did not compose the hymn.

Comment: @Dom - Music history seems like a better fit for our site than for Music Practice

Comment: @ChrisSunamisupportsMonica I answered in the meta too, but Music SE does have history questions and this being in the domain of practice and theory rather than appreciation it makes much more sense there. This user also has a habit of using this SE as a secondary Music SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale already existed. (In fact, the diatonic scale, though in a somewhat different but analogous form, goes back at least to [ancient Greece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatonic_scale).) Guido d'Arezzo just created the mnemonic that stuck.

Comment: In addition, Guido did not compose the hymn.